# Vertical Scroll on <div> Not Working When <div> overflow-x: hidden Is Given On Touch Phone

Tags: css, html, dom, scroll

When I give `overflow: hidden` to a `<div>` & swipe my finger vertically to scroll, it doesn't scroll on touch device in UC Browser & Android Default Browser.

**Can we fix this via JavaScript?**

**Edit**

**I don't want to scroll inside the `<div>`. I want to scroll vertically in the document.** But, when there is horizontal scroll bar in the `<div>`, & I try to scroll vertically, document doesn't scroll vertically.

**How to fix this?**

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's normal, as `overflow: hidden` does exactly that: tell the browser not to display the content that overflows the element and not to let the content scroll.

If you want your content to not overflow the element, but be able to scroll, do this:

```
overflow: auto;
```

or

```
overflow: scroll;
```

The difference? `auto` will show scroll bars when needed (when the content is wider or higher than the container), while `scroll` will show scrollbars **always**. Of course, in a touch device there is no difference.

If what you want is to scroll vertically, but not horizontally, you can use the specific properties:

```
overflow-x: hidden;  /*don't scroll, nor show the overflow content horizontally*/
overflow-y: auto;    /*allow scrolling vertically when needed */
```

Comment: Then we need more markup and CSS. Ideally, a jsfiddle